# What is the relationship between quantum dissipative system and quantum impurity system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, phase-transition, many-body, dissipation

Now I'm studying the phase transition of the many-body system as a school degree.
What I'm curious that, I found the meaning of quantum impurity system is : One particle interacts with an ensemble system.
Is quantum dissipative system can be one of the Quantum impurity systems?

Comment: Generally we try to have one question per post on this site. I would suggest deleting the parts of this question about coherent states and asking them in a separate question

Comment: @BySymmetry I've edited it, Thanks for the comment!